getter method vs computed signal in angular service
I have a confusion in the following stackblitz:
here
In here it has uses signal to set state and getter method to get the data in the view.
Can we use computed() method of signal and get the latest changes in the view?
I tried this.
Service:
import { Injectable, computed, signal } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor() { }

  firstName = signal('Pial');
  lastName = signal('Noman');

  fullName = computed(() => this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName());

}

component:
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-user',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './update-user.component.html',
  styleUrl: './update-user.component.css'
})
export class UpdateUserComponent {

  userService = inject(UserService);

  firstName = this.userService.firstName();
  lastName = this.userService.lastName();

  updateUserName(e: any, firstName: string, lastName: string) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.userService.firstName.set(firstName);
    this.userService.lastName.set(lastName);
  }

}

another component:
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-com-2',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './com-2.component.html',
  styleUrl: './com-2.component.css'
})
export class Com2Component {

  userService = inject(UserService);

  fullName = this.userService.fullName();

}


Your StackBlitz example appears to be functioning correctly, but the code there differs from what you've described. Could you clarify your question? What specific issue are you encountering?

I was confused about why we should use the getter method but it is the way Angular signal documentation said. Now the confusion is clear.
